# Django | Checkbox de FORM HTML por POST devuelve lista vacía y no el valor del mismo

Tags: django

Los checkbox los devuelve sin contenido, en cambio el answer devuelve corréctamente:
¿Cómo se debería hacer para poder conseguir el valor del checkbox?
Gracias.

**View:**

```
def saveUserAnswer(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        answerCorrect = request.POST['answer']
        userAnswerA = request.POST.getlist('nameCheckboxA')
        userAnswerB = request.POST.getlist('nameCheckboxB')
        userAnswerC = request.POST.getlist('nameCheckboxC')
        userAnswerD = request.POST.getlist('nameCheckboxD')
        
        print(answerCorrect)
        print(userAnswerA)
        print(userAnswerB)
        print(userAnswerC)
        print(userAnswerD)
```

**Salida consola:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**HTML:**

```
<form class="form-signin p-1" action="{% url 'test_app:saveUserAnswer' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      

    {% for tes in object_list %}
  <div class="text-center mb-4">
    <h3 class="h4 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-secondary">{{ tes.nameModality }}</h3>
  </div>      
  <div class="text-left mb-4">
    <h3 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">{{ tes.number }}.-{{ tes.question }}</h3>
  </div>


  <div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label class="ml-4">
      <input id="idCheckboxA" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="A" name="nameCheckboxA" /><a id="aidCheckboxA"> A .-{{ tes.a }}</a><br>
      <input id="idCheckboxB" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="B" name="nameCheckboxB" /><a id="aidCheckboxB"> B .-{{ tes.b }}</a><br>
      <input id="idCheckboxC" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="C" name="nameCheckboxC" /><a id="aidCheckboxC"> C .-{{ tes.c }}</a><br>
      <input id="idCheckboxD" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="D" name="nameCheckboxD" /><a id="aidCheckboxD"> D .-{{ tes.d }}</a><br>
      <input id="Answer" style="visibility:hidden" type="hidden" name="answer" value="{{ tes.get_answer_display }}"><br>
    </label>

 
{% endfor %}
  </div>
  <button id="correctButton" style="background-color:#250F64; color:white; display:block" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="button" onclick="correct()">Corregir</button>
  <button id="nextButton" style="background-color:#250F64; color:white; display:none" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Siguiente</button>
  <a href="{% url 'home_app:home' %}"><p class="text-center mt-3">Volver a la página principal</p></a>


</form>
```

Comment: Mmm. Es raro.  ¿Sería el botón de corregir? Simulé y me llega correctamente. Si marco la opción A por ejemplo me llega `['A']`. Eso sí, cambié el `type` de corregir a `submit`.

Comment: Bueno, el primer botón que comentas lo utilizo para una corrección mediante javascript utilizando la respuesta bueno que está oculta. He probado como dices utilizar ese mismo botón cambiando a sumbit, pero me devuelve lista vacía. ¿Es al value lo que debería llegar, verdad? Es decir, tal y como tengo, pulsando A, debería llegar una simple "A" entiendo.

Comment: Sí, con lo que coloques en `name` puedes recibir la lista en `views` y el `value` del `input` es lo que te llegará como valor dentro de la lista.

Comment: Sí, es curioso que paso otros input por post, y llegan perfecto. Pero el checkbox se me resiste. Entiendo que en el caso de checkbox se pone así en la View; request.POST.getlist('nameCheckboxA') en cambio los input por ejemplo tipo text así: request.POST['answer']. Si pongo al checkbox así: request.POST('nameCheckboxA') Me devuelve "TypeError at /test/saveUserAnswer
'QueryDict' object is not callable"

Comment: Al final como no llegaba el checkbox a la view por post, he creado en el template un input oculto tipo text, que con javascript le doy el value del checkbox seleccionado. Esto al ser un input normal, me deja pasarlo por post sin ningún problema. Gracias Adrián.

Comment: Nada, ret. Me alegro ayudar.

Comment: Los checkbox son un elemento endiablado, si el valor es True sí se envían, pero si el valor es false no se envían en absoluto. Ese puede ser el origen del problema.

Comment: Gracias Sokkian. De todos modos había probado seleccionándo uno u otro cada vez que hacía la prueba y nada. Devuelve lista vacía. Por eso al final por javascript he copiado a otro input oculto (hidden) tipo text el check elegido, y así este input sí que puedo pasar sin ningún problema. Me he quedado con el misterio de no poder pasar el checked por Post. (No dudo que algo habré hecho mal, pero es curioso que Adrián lo haya probado tal cual parece ser y le haya pasado por Post ese "deseado" True). Un saludo Sokkian. ; )